# aligning text in a table

Tags: tables

I have problem with aligning text in a table. Here is my example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{tabular}{| l | p{1.5cm} | p{1.5cm}| }
      \hline
         & percentage difference &  key size increase \\ \hline
      N = 90 trials &  2.1 \% &  76 \% \\ \hline
      N = 180 trials & 1.3 \% &  40 \% \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Caption here.}
\end{figure}                     
\end{document}
```

[image]

the problem is a cell with text 'key size increase', there is big space between
words 'key' and 'size', how can I fix it.

Comment: Not related to your question: If you use the float environment `table` isntead of `figure` for your `tabular` you will get a “Table” caption and the `\listoftables` and `\listoffigures` would have the right contents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `\parbox` justifies its content. That’s the reason why there's so much space between “key” und “size”.

I find the table column specifier `p{<width>}` in this case very unsatisfying as the resulting column has a *minimum* width.

I'd rather insert manually line-breaks with one of the following solutions:

- **`\lbCell`**: An inner `tabular` that exists of only one column (I prefer a `c`entered heading),
- **`\pCell`**: a `\pbox[<vertical alignment>]{<maximum width>}{<content>}`.
  The `\pbox` macro is provided by the [`pbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pbox) package. The resulting box collapses to the minimal required width.

The first optional argument of both `\*Cell` macros denote the vertical alignment of the insertes `tabular`/`pbox` and is per default `t`op.

Not related to you question, I also uses the [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package to provide a more appealing output *(so many lines!)* of your tabular.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand*{\lbCell}[2][t]{%
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}%
    #2%
    \end{tabular}%
}
\usepackage{pbox}
\newcommand*{\pCell}[2][t]{% needs manual line-breaks!
    \pbox[#1]{\linewidth}{#2\strut}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
    \toprule
                                 & \lbCell{percentage\\difference} & \lbCell{key size\\increase} \\ \midrule
    $N = \hphantom{1}90$ trials  &             2.1 \%              &            76 \%            \\
    $N = 180$ trials             &             1.3 \%              &            40 \%            \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{lcc}
    \toprule
                                 & \pCell{percentage\\difference} & \pCell{key size\\increase} \\ \midrule
    $N = \hphantom{1}90$ trials  &             2.1 \%             &           76 \%            \\
    $N = 180$ trials             &             1.3 \%             &           40 \%            \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 5):

One work around is to load `array` package by typing `\usepackage{array}` in the preamble then put `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}` before `p{1.5cm}` in your last column.

Here is the output.

[image]

Another option is to define a `newcolumntype` like the one I did below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{| l | p{1.5cm} | L| }
      \hline
         & percentage difference &  key size increase \\ \hline
      N = 90 trials &  2.1 \% &  76 \% \\ \hline
      N = 180 trials & 1.3 \% &  40 \% \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Caption here.}
\end{figure}                     
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Though this will cause slight alignment issues, I would put your text in a `parbox`:

```
\parbox{1.5cm}{\raggedright{}key size increase}
```

It looks to me like the only reason you're using the column style `p{1.5cm}` is to create a box for the column titles.  I'd approach this differently by writing

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{tabular}{| l | c | c | }
      \hline
     \rule[-0.5ex]{0pt}{0.5ex}    & \parbox[b]{1.5cm}{\raggedright{}percentage difference} & \parbox[b]{1.5cm}{\raggedright key size increase} \\ \hline
      N = 90 trials &  2.1 \% &  76 \% \\ \hline
      N = 180 trials & 1.3 \% &  40 \% \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Caption here.}
\end{figure}                     
\end{document}
```

This way, I've created two `parboxes` aligned on their baselines.  The `\rule[-0.5ex]{0pt}{0.5ex}` creates a vertical strut so that the boxes don't lie too close to the `hline` below them.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: In this instance `\rule` doesn't change anything due the `[b]` aligning. I'd recommend `\rule[-.3\normalbaselineskip]{0pt}{2\normalbaselineskip}` here.